# Dictionary of supposedly distinct objects all seem to refer to each other

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm iterating through a string to convert it into a different data structure; that being a dictionary of objects, where the key is the k-length substring at the current position in the main string and the value is an object which counts the occurrences of that substring within "frames" of the main string (i.e., L-length substrings). I only keep a count up to a certain threshold, once that has passed, that key gets added to a bucket which is ultimately returned.

```
class kmerRecord:
  _inFrames = {}
  _threshold = None

  reachedThreshold = False

  def __init__(self, threshold, inFrames = []):
    self._threshold = threshold
    if inFrames:
      self.incrementFrames(inFrames)

  # Debug
  def __repr__(self):
    return '<in: ' + str(self._inFrames) + ', t: ' + str(self.reachedThreshold) + '>'

  def incrementFrames(self, inFrames):
    if not self.reachedThreshold:
      for f in inFrames:
        if f in self._inFrames:
          self._inFrames[f] += 1
          if self._inFrames[f] >= self._threshold:
            self.reachedThreshold = True
            break
        else:
          self._inFrames[f] = 1


def kmerClump(data, k, L, t):
  kmers = {}
  found = []
  N = len(data)

  for i in range(N - k + 1):
    kmer = data[i : i + k]
    inFrames = range(max(0, i - L + k), min(i, N - L) + 1)

    if kmer in kmers:
      kmers[kmer].incrementFrames(inFrames)
    else:
      kmers[kmer] = kmerRecord(t, inFrames)

    # Debug
    # print kmer, min(inFrames), max(inFrames), kmers

    if kmers[kmer].reachedThreshold:
      found.append(kmer)

  return found
```

As far as I can see, my code is doing what I've described above. However, it doesn't work and when I try outputting the dictionary and objects, it appears as though every object in the dictionary is the same: As though there's actually only one object and the other key values are just references to that, rather than distinct objects. Have I got the semantics wrong, somewhere, or is there another problem?

Comment: You are sharing and mutating the class attribute.

Comment: Your `inFrames` default for the `__init__` method could also be shared, see ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going mad!!